# Removing item from RecyclerView

Tags: android

I am having trouble removing items from RecyclerView.  When I click on delete, the item is removed from RecyclerView, but comes back when I open the app again.  I'm hoping it is just a minor issue that someone here can point out or direct me to what area to troubleshoot.  The removeItem(String item) in bold is what I think is the issue.  You can't see it in this post, but it is "not used".

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Grocery> mListData;
    private SQLGroceryHelper helper;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

    //Adapter's Constructor//
    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Grocery> mDataList) {
        this.mListData = mDataList;
    }

    //Provide a reference to the views for each contact item//
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView rowItem;
        ImageButton purchasedButton;
        ImageButton deleteButton;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_row);
            rowItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_field1);
            purchasedButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_purchased);
            deleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_item);
        }
    }

    //Inflate the view based on the viewtype provided//
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Create a new view by inflating the row item xml//
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false);

        //Set the view to the ViewHolder//
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
        return holder;
    }

    //Display data at the specified position//
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.rowItem.setText(mListData.get(position).getTextItem());
        holder.purchasedButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            //Ignore this click for now//
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    public void **removeItem**(String item) {
        int position = mListData.indexOf(item);
        if (position != -1) {
            mListData.remove(item);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mListData.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mListData == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return mListData.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you removing the data from your database?

Comment: where are you initializing `RecyclerViewAdapter`? The error might be because in the way how you are initializing the adapter or how you are adding the data to list. Please post the code to find the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You are removing the data from local object, `mListData` I guess the original data object remains intact. Remove the data item from the original data object as well

Declare a interface

`public interface AdapterCommunication{
     void removeStringItem(int position);
}`

then in your adapter

```
private AdapterCommunication mListener;

public void setOnClickListener(AdapterCommunication listener){
              mListener = listener;
}
```

Then from your activity where you initialize the adapter

```
RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);

adapter.setOnClickListener(new AdapterCommunication{

 public void removeStringItem(int position){
     list.remove(position);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
});
```

In your adaper,

```
holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mListener.remove(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Some reason, i'm not able to delete String item.  Not sure if i'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: post your code related to removing string item from original data object

Comment: public void removeItem(String item) {
        int position = mListData.indexOf(item);
        if (position != -1) {
            mListData.remove(item);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

Comment: looking at the comment, I can tell that you are not removing the string object from the original one.

You are calling the adapter by `new RecyclerViewAdapter(dataObject)`, you need to remove the string item  from this dataObject as well

Comment: I agree with you.  I'm just not sure how to go about removing the String item.  or Maybe I need to remove it from a different location.  I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: @Kimo were you able to solve your problem with the updated answer?

Comment: I haven't been stallianz.  I made a duplicate with listView, seems easier.  It just doesn't look as nice.

Comment: if you solved your problem, please post your solution

Comment: please can you help me? i am having a similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088451/java-android-remove-a-recylerview-item