# Java Android Remove a recylerview item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am developing an activity that shows the posts of the users followed. To do this, I set the query to point to the user's following and fetch the information by inserting it on the cardview on the onBindViewHolder in this way:

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<GetInfoPost> options
                = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<GetInfoPost>()
                .setQuery(FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("following").document(fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).collection("/userFollowing").limit(1000), GetInfoPost.class)
                .build();


        FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder> firestoreRecyclerAdapter

                =new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<GetInfoPost, FindFriendsViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FindFriendsViewHolder findFriendsViewHolder, int i, @NonNull GetInfoPost getInfoPost) {

                final String listUserId = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(i).getId();




                FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                Query userPostsRef = rootRef.collection("post").document(listUserId).collection("userPosts").limit(1);
                userPostsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String postID = "";
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, document.getId() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                postID = document.getId();
                            }

                            String finalPostID = postID;

                            if(finalPostID.equals("")){

                                return;
                            }

                            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("likes").document(finalPostID).collection("postLikes").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                                        int count = 0;
                                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                            count++;
                                        }
                                        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
                                        findFriendsViewHolder.txtLikenmb.setText(count + "");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
```

Everything seems to work except that when a user who follows you (or more users) does not have a post, the recylerview still creates an item and in order not to crash the app I did this:

```
                         if(finalPostID.equals("")){

                                return;
                            }
```

But I would like not to show that empty post:

[image]

So is there a way to delete an item from the recyclerview?

(I tried looking at similar questions but they all used an array list or something so they didn't help me)

Comment: I don't think that using firebase queries like `userPostsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener` in `onBindViewHolder` is a good approach, because this gets consume the the quota every time the recyclerView recycle views even if they already have been fetched before.

Comment: @Zain maybe you are right but it is the only way I have found to show posts of followed users

Comment: @Zain do you know if there is a way to delete an element?